# "of which" vs. "that"

Tags: relative-pronouns

I'm going to write two short sentences and then I will ask my question:

1. **Sentence 1:**

   - Women have the more risk for stroke more than men, but men have more risk for heart attack than women.
2. **Sentence 2:**

   - Because of that, both of the genders should be aware about their life style.

**The question:** 
Can I say about the first sentence: *"The statement **of which** I opened with, is true and it's proved scientifically."* and will it have an equal meaning if I use "**that**" instead of "**of which**" *(I mean if I replace them)*?

Comment: Incidentally, on reading the message in your profile I realized you have a mistake with the relative clause: "Feel free to correct me about anything that you think it will make me better." It should be: "Feel free to correct me about anything that you think will make me better." The relative "that" refers to "anything" and functions as the subject of the content clause inside the relative clause, which makes "it" unnecessary and incorrect: "You think X will make me better" -> "...about anything that (subsitutes for X) you think will make me better."

Comment: Also, don't take the tag "conjunctions" seriously. Your question is about relative pronouns, and relative pronouns are NOT conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

You *open with* a statement.

The statement **with** which you opened...

The statement (that) you opened **with**...

You *speak of* a person.

The person **of** whom I spoke...

The person (who) I spoke **of**...

You *sit on* a chair.

The chair **on** which I sat...

The chair (that) I sat **on**...

You *travel to* a destination.

The destination **to** which I traveled...

The destination (that) I traveled **to** ...

You *walk along* a river bank.

The river bank **along** which I walked...

The river bank (that) I walked **along**...

You live *under* a roof.

The roof **under** which I lived...

The roof (that) I lived **under**...

You look *through* a telescope.

The telescope **through** which I looked...

The telescope (that) I looked **through**...